# How to get textfields data in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Textfield which has a controller so I can grab data from it.
But how can I do it when I create an input by a button click, for example, I created 10 text fields how can I get data from them?

Thanks for your answers but you did not understand me, I can't just create controllers manually, I have a button once I clicked upon it a new textfield is created, I can click on it as many times as I want it can be 100 times for example, because of this I need to do it programmatically if it is possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** added lines about accessing the text inside each controller

You could try keeping a `List` of `TextEditingControllers`.

When the button is pushed you will add a new `TextEditingController` to the `List` and then create the new `TextField` that the controller will be connected to.

Then to get the contents of each controller just iterate through the `List` and access the `text` member of the controller.

Just remember you will have to go through that `List` in your widget's `dispose` method and call their `dispose` methods as well.

```
final List<TextEditingController> _controllers = []

void onButtonPress() {
  TextEditingController newController = TextEditingController()
  _controllers.push(newController)
  // Make new TextField and use the new controller in it
  // Then figure out how to add the new TextField to your state (probably using setState)
}
```

Comment: I think you meant .add() not .push()

Answer (score 0):

in on pressed method :

```
(){
    //this will get the last input that user entered in the textfield
   String data = _myController.text;

    if(data.isEmpty) 
      //do something 
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final controllerOne= TextEditingController();
final controllerTwo= TextEditingController();


TextFiledOne(
controller: controllerOne,
....
);

TextFiledTwo(
controller: controllerTwo,
....
);


onPressed(){
 String dataOne = controllerOne.text;
 String dataTwo = controllerTwo.text;
....
}
```